# Uploadify in Chrome return Aw, Snap page

Tags: php, flash, uploadify

from last update of chrome (Version 36.0.1985.125 m) i have problem with uplodify plugin/flash. Chrome shows Aw, Snap Page or sometimes He's Dead, Jim!. Here is my uplodify code:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload_50">
<script type="text/javascript">
var basePath = "path to ressources";
var errorMessage = "Error Message";
var allowExts = "*.pdf; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.rar; *.zip";
$(document).ready(function() {
    var is_error = false;
    $('#file_upload_50').uploadify({
        'swf': basePath + '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': "uploader.php",
        'height': 25,
        'buttonText': "Upload",
        'fileTypeExts': allowExts,
        'fileTypeDesc': "Formats:" + allowExts,
        'formData': {
            'user_id': 50,
            'company_id': 1
        },
        'onUploadError': function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
            alert(errorMessage);
            is_error = true;
        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (!result.result) {
                alert(result.error_msg);
                is_error = true;
            }
        },
        'onQueueComplete': function(queueData) {
            if (!is_error) {
                document.location.href = "result_page.html";
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Where is the problem? Can you get me some advice. I am helpless. Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the exact same version of Chrome. My website uses uploadify as well. I've recently been getting Aw Snap on Chrome quite often. I'd think this probably has something to do with Chrome or Flash's latest update.

Comment: Try disabling uploadify cache

Comment: I have never used Uploadify, but just wondering: Why do you even need Flash for that in Chrome? Isn't it supposed to fall back to Flash only when HTML5 File API is not available?

Answer (score 15):

I've found that adding a `setTimeout` fixes this. This would indicate a race condition in Chrome / Chrome's Flash implementation / Uploadify's Flash app, the circumstances of which are not clear. Nonetheless, it appears to work in all situations for our use case.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('foo').uploadify({...});
    }, 0);
});
```

This isn't a *good* answer, but in the absence of a solution, it's a usable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to cache most of the time.. try to change your Javascript include as below and error will be gone!.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="<<path-to-uploadify>>/jquery.uploadify-3.1.js?ver=<?php echo rand(0,999999);?>"></script>
```

Comment: it fixed the Aw, Snap page~ but can u explain how this worked ? because when put this code on the page , the page will load very slow

Answer (score -1):

If this is your current code - shouldn't the 'basePath' be a relative/direct url ?

So, instead of

```
var basePath = "path to ressources";
```

Shouldn't it be more like

```
var basePath = "/assets/RESOURCE_FOLDERNAME";
```

or an empty string ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you - but try debugging the upload process using chrome Inspector, and the Network tab. You should be able to see  your requests and their server status (like 500, or 200). This might help you narrow down the main issue, as it seems to me, that there is something bad "under the hood"

Comment: thank you, but in network inspector is all ok. i think it is problem "under the hood" too.

Comment: The same thing has started happening to me as well. Everything was fine, now I get the 'Aw Snap' page every time, ever since updating Chrome to the latest version. It works fine in IE and it even works if I simply refresh the page so I have no idea what's going on.