# When i use google chrome browser version 36.0.1985.125 m. "Aw, Snap!" error comes with uploadify.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Following error comes with google chrome browser, which version is 36.0.1985.125 m.

Error : "Aw, Snap!" error

when i use uploadify code then,"Aw, Snap!" error comes on submit of data.
when i comment this uploadify then, no error comes.

Thanks in advance.

Can you please help me.

Comment: In English: could you show some code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951141/uploadify-in-chrome-return-aw-snap-page

Comment: Show us the working and not-working code please